# Django test __str__(self) for ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

So I have this ForeignKey in my class **Adress**:

```
class Adresse(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.place.city
```

The ForeignKey comes from the Model **Place**:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city
```

When I run the server, everything works as intended and my **Adress** returns the Foreign Key from the other class.
I want to know how to write a test for this, so far my *test_models.py* file is looking like this:

```
class TestForeignKey(TestCase):

    def test_adress_str(self):
        testing_city = Adresse.objects.create(place.city = 'London')

        self.assertEqual(str(testing_city), 'London')
```

but I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests/test_models.py", line 8, in test_adress_str
    testing_city = Adress.objects.create(city = 'London')
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 445, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/jmihretab/Desktop/TEST/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Adress() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city'
```

Anyone that can help?

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback?

Comment: `Adresse.objects.create(place.city = 'London')` how is this valid syntax?? You should get some error like `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes you are correct this actually returns a SyntaxError, but if I just do ```city = 'London' ``` I would get this Error. ```TypeError: Adress() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city'```

Answer (score 1):

Django cannot magically create an instance of `Place` just by you writing:

```
Adresse.objects.create(place.city = 'London')
```

In fact this is not even valid syntax. You need to **explicitly make an instance of `Place`** yourself and assign it:

```
class TestForeignKey(TestCase):

    def test_adress_str(self):
        place = Place.objects.create(city='London')
        testing_city = Adresse.objects.create(place=place)

        self.assertEqual(str(testing_city), 'London')
```